# Regex to not match a number sequence like '1111111111', 2's, 3's, 4's etc

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to capture the consecutive number sequence in asp.net like repeated 1's, 2's and so on?
I tried ^([0-9])\1{3}$ and many other ways but did not worked for me. Is that not really possible to capture the consecutive number?

Comment: How about something like - `\b(\d)\1*\b` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, and it seems you did it as

```cs
Regex.IsMatch(text, @"^([0-9])\1+$")
```

will match `111111`, `222222222222`etc.

See [regex proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5B0-9%5D%29%5C1%2B%24&i=222222222222).

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1+                      what was matched by capture \1 (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```